# Is serial queue(other than Main) code execute on Main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

1) Serial queues in ios created by

`_queue = dispatch_queue_create("serial-queue-1", nil);`

runs on Main thread or some different thread.

And

2) If it runs on Main thread then if we syncronously dispatch the block of code to the above queue by

`dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{
      method1();
      method2();
 });`

Would it execute the complete block of code when this queue gets its turn or it can also leave this queue to execute some other in between ?

Comment: No, it's just create separate serial queue

Comment: Yeah creates separate serial queue but i need to know that it runs that queue code on main thread or some other thread?

Comment: I have told you: separate

Comment: Thanks could you provide me some reference for this to read it thouroughly.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453030-dispatch_queue_create\

Comment: But there is not clearly that the blocks submitted to these queues runs on different thread other than main thread.

Comment: "Note, however, that blocks submitted to **independent** queues may be executed **concurrently** with respect to each other"

Answer (score 0):

In general, a block that is dispatched on a queue can run on any available thread, including the main thread.  The exception to this is that a block dispatched on the main queue will always run on the main thread.

When you use `dispatch_sync` on a serial queue it blocks the current *queue*, but not the current *thread*.

From the [`dispatch_sync` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452870-dispatch_sync?language=objc)

> Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock.

If you target the current queue using `dispatch_sync` you will get a deadlock, but if you target a different queue you will not get a deadlock, even if the dispatched block ends up on the same thread.

In fact:

> As a performance optimization, this function executes blocks on the current thread whenever possible

So, presuming that the `dispatch_sync` in your question was called from the main queue, the block will run on the main thread, since you have blocked the main queue and the main thread is therefore available to perform the work.

iOS multitasking is not pre-emptive, so your block cannot "lose" the thread; the block will execute in its entirety before relinquishing the thread. This is assuming that `method1` and `method2` do not dispatch further blocks themselves.